# read_osm from tmap package gives transformation error

Tags: gdal, r, openstreetmap, rgdal, tmap

I try to read Open Street Map data as shown in the RDocumentation of the tmap package.

```
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
data(NLD_muni)
osm_NLD <- read_osm(NLD_muni, ext=1.1)
```

But I get following error:

> Error: OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation(): transformation not available
> In addition: Warning message:
> In CPL_transform(x, crs, aoi, pipeline, reverse, desired_accuracy,  :
> GDAL Error 1: No PROJ.4 translation for destination SRS, coordinate transformation initialization has failed.

This worked some months ago and GDAL is working properly in other calculations. So now I am asking myself if there is a problem with the tmaptools package.

Comment: My `tmap` (v 3.3-4) doesn't have a `read_osm` function - where are you getting it from? [update] `tmaptools` I think...

Comment: This works for me with the latest CRAN versions of `tmap` and `tmaptools`. Do you get any CRS errors or warnings with `plot(NLD_muni$geom)` or `st_transform(NLD_muni, 3857)` or `st_transform(NLD_muni, 4326)`? I think its not `tmap` struggling here but something else and we need to eliminate...

Comment: Yes the 3 suggested operations work properly.  I get ```old-style crs object detected; please recreate object with a recent sf::st_crs()``` as a warning, but the warning dosent show up if i use ```st_crs(NLD_muni) = st_crs(NLD_muni)``` beforehand

Comment: Which two CRS? Could a possible transformation/operation use a file that wasn't installed?